# Why I am getting a http request exception in Xamarin Forms

Tags: exception, xamarin.forms, httprequest

I am trying to execute this simple code but it fails and i get System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

The code simply declares an HttpCLient and then I use the GetStringMethod. the same code used to work. I don't know why it doesn't now.
I searched google and stackoverflow and couldn't get the answer.

Here is my .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using FetchActor.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections;

namespace FetchActor
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {




        HttpClient connection = new HttpClient();
        MovieService movieService = new MovieService();




        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }




        private async void searchBarByActor_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            var _connection = await connection.GetStringAsync("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/keyword?api_key=ab3da1af35c55cc8b3780fbc9a2bf259&amp;query=Charlize%20Theron&amp;page=1");
        }

    }
}
```

the code never goes past GetStringAsync and i get the error. 
any ideas on what could this be please ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the emulator wasn't get data from the connection. I turned the Wifi on and off and restarted the computer and the project. it still didn't work. it was showing connected but no internet.

the solution was turning off mobile data in the emulator so that it could be connected only with wifi.